# MSC Service working on WildFly 9, stops working on WildFly 10

Tags: java, service, wildfly-10

I'm trying to move our web application from Wildfly 9.0.2 to **Wildfly 10.1.0**.

At startup, we initialize the database with Flyway and use a `org.jboss.msc.service.Service` for that. It was working well on WF9 but failed on WF10, and I can't figure what we're doing wrong.

In an ApplicationScoped class, we call the service like this (I rewrited the code a bit for the clarity of the question):

```
// get the service factory    
ServiceName factoryServiceName = SingletonServiceName.BUILDER.getServiceName("server");
ServiceController<?> factoryService = context.getServiceRegistry().getRequiredService(factoryServiceName);
SingletonServiceBuilderFactory factory = factoryService.getValue();

// get the specific service
ServiceName serviceName = ServiceName.of("com.example.DatabaseSingletonService");
ServiceController<Boolean> databaseSingletonService = factory
    .createSingletonServiceBuilder(serviceName, service)
    .electionPolicy(new SimpleSingletonElectionPolicy())
    .requireQuorum(1)
    .build(serviceActivatorContext.getServiceTarget())
    .setInitialMode(Mode.ACTIVE)
    .install();

// call the service
boolean checked = databaseSingletonService.awaitValue(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

The service itself is something like this:

```
public class DatabaseSingletonService implements Service<Boolean>
{
    private Boolean check;

    @Override
    public Boolean getValue() throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException
    {
        System.out.println("getValue: " + check);
        return check;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(StartContext context) throws StartException
    {
        System.out.println("start");
        check = /* flyway calls and other processes, returning true */
        System.out.println("check now is: " + check);
    }
}
```

Problem is, the service call with `.awaitValue()` returns `null` instead of `true` because it doesn't wait anything. The traces show the problem, where `getValue()` is called too soon:

```
> (MSC service thread 1-4) start
> (thread-1,ee,pc-xp)      getValue: null
> (MSC service thread 1-4) check now is: true
```

Trying to look in the `ServiceController` implementation, it seems to not wait because it considers the service as already UP.

Reading the Service javadoc, I understand that if the `start()` method is doing something that can block or wait, we have to call `context.asynchronous()`, but I cannot find any examples of the right way to use that. I tried this, without success:

```
public void start(StartContext context) throws StartException
{
    context.asynchronous();
    context.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            check = check();
        }
    });
    context.complete();
}
```

What could cause this problem in WF10 but not in WF9? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The simplest solution would probably be to just make the methods `synchronized`.

Comment: Seems a bit a hack to me, but it works :)

Comment: Well not really. I mean services are meant to be thread safe given the code snippet it doesn't look like it is thread safe. I don't know what the `awaitValue` method looks like so maybe you handle it in there.

Comment: A bit late, but for others that may have a similar problem: `context.complete()` / `context.failed(...)` must be invoked inside the `Runnable`. Those methods signal that the service initialization is done. Your `context.complete()` might be invoked before the `Runnable` is picked up by a thread. Additionally: Do NOT use `context.execute(...)` for blocking tasks, as described in the javadoc. Better is to resolve the servers `Executor Service` (`Services.addServerExecutorDependency(...)` / `Services.requireServerExecutor(...)`). And finally `awaitValue` is deprecated in current WildFly versions